# Sem permissão de acesso para Apache 2.4.6

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Fiz uma atualização do Ubuntu 13.04 para o 13.10, mas quando fui verificar o Apache usando `localhost/` estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Poste o seu apache.conf em `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` e tambem as configurações do seu site em /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf (o 000-default.conf pode ter outro nome), coloque na pasta www um arquivo index.html e veja se consegue acessa-lo tambem atraves de localhost/ ou localhost/index.html se tiver algum arquivo **.htaccess** na sua pasta www mostre tambem.

Comment: A partir da versão 2.4 do Apache, sua raiz foi mudada para `/var/www/html/`. 1 - Você poderá colocar seus projetos dentro de `/var/www/html/` ao invés de `/var/www/`. E acessá-los normalmente em `localhost/seuProjeto`. 2 - Ou você poderá mudar a configuração da raiz para `/var/www/` modificando o **DocumentRoot** no arquivo `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.

Comment: Quando aconteceu isso comigo, fui no arquivo: /etc/apache2/conf-available/php5-fpm.conf Substitui todos os: Order Deny,Allow Deny from all Por: Require all granted E deletei no apache2.conf: <Directory /> AllowOverride none Require all denied </Directory>

Comment: Tenta um **`chmod a+rw index.html`** no diretório raiz do seu apache e observe o log de erros pelo comando `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` e poste o log, se não conseguir.

Comment: Amigo, verifique as permissões no arquivo de configuração do seu apache. Isso depende de qual serviço você utiliza para webserver local, mas é um arquivo com a extensão .conf. Em pacotes como o WAMP no próprio menu você consegue o caminho para editá-lo, precisará achar a linha Order Deny,Allow E então fornecer a ordem para permitir em localhost: Allow from 127.0.0.1 OBS: Como não sou um usuário Linux não sei te informar a localização do arquivo. Espero ter ajudado, qualquer duvida estou a disposição.